# Setting regular expression to validate URL format in Adobe CQ5

Tags: regex, aem

I want to validate a URL inside a textfield using Adobe CQ5, so I set up the properties regex and regexText as usual, but for some reason is not working:

```html
                <facebook
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    emptyText="http://www.facebook.com/account-name"
                    fieldDescription="Set the Facebook URL"
                    fieldLabel="Facebook"
                    name="./facebookUrl"
                    regex="/^(http://www.|https://www.|http://|https://)[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(/.*)?$/"
                    regexText="Invalid URL format"
                    xtype="textfield"/>
```

So when I type inside the component I can see an error message at the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.regex.test is not a function
```

To be more accurate the error comes from this line:

```js
        if (this.regex && !this.regex.test(value)) {
```

I tried several regular expressions and none of them worked. I guess the problem is the regular expression itself, because in the other hand I have this other regex to evaluate email address, and it works perfectly fine:

```
/^[A-za-z0-9]+[\\._]*[A-za-z0-9]*@[A-za-z.-]+[\\.]+[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems like '/' is a delimiter in your tool. In your regex, you use "http://", so my guess is that the first slash of '//' is interpreted as the end of the regex. The rest then provokes an error... Is there some way of escaping the slashes in your language ?

Comment: I tried modifying the regex following your advice:

^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|http:\/\/|https:\/\/)[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\/.*)?$

But same result :(

Comment: I tried your regex in C++ and it worked perfectly fine. Maybe try to escape the slashes twice, like that : "http:\\/\\/" ?

Comment: Thanks so much, there it was the problem:

/^(http:\\/\\/www.|https:\\/\\/www.|http:\\/\\/|https:\\/\\/)[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\\/.*)?$/

This one worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax of your regex seems to treat the forward slashes (/) as special characters. Since you want to parse a URL containing slashes, my guess is you should escape them twice like this: '\\/' instead of '/'. The result would be:

```
/^(http:\\/\\/www.|https:\\/\\/www.|http:\\/\\/|https:\\/\\/)[a-z0-9]+([-.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)‌​*.[a-z]{2,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?(\\/.*)?$/
```

You need to escape them twice because the **string to be compiled as a regex** must contain '\/' to escape the slashes, but to introduce a backslash in a string you have to escape the backslash itself too.